# How are Zhang-Safavi-Susilo signatures short?

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature

ZSS signatures have been introduced by Fangguo Zhang, Reihaneh Safavi-Naini, and Willy Susilo: [*An Efficient Signature Scheme from Bilinear Pairings and Its Applications*](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-540-24632-9_20.pdf), in [proceedings of PKC 2004](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-24632-9_20).
Standardization at IETF was attempted with [*ZSS Short Signature Scheme for Supersingular and BN Curves*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-zss-02) [*].

The example given in [appendix C.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-zss-02#appendix-C.1) for supersingular curves has 2048-bit signature for 128-bit security (256-bit hash); [appendix C.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-zss-02#appendix-C.2) for Barreto-Naerhig curves has about 1012-bit signature for 112-bit security (about 224-bit hash).
This is a lot more than 512-bit signature of DSA or ECDSA of [FIPS186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf), or [Ed25519](http://ed25519.cr.yp.to/), at comparable conjectured security level.

In what sense, or compared to what, can ZSS signatures be qualified as ***short***?

---

[*] My guess is that this draft merges [*ZSS Short Signature Scheme*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hitt-zss-02) and [*ZSS Short Signature Scheme for BN Curves*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-zssbn-01).

Comment: The signature is one element of an elliptic curve group and thus identical to the size of BLS signatures. You can use point compression to reduce the size by a factor of $2$ and I guess that is what is assumed to be done.

Comment: @Drlecter: even if we assume that in the examples that I link to,  point compression could be used, but is not, the signatures are not more compact than Schnorr signatures, and there remains a wide gap with BLS signature, which is [said](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/112145/6211) to be about 256-bit for 128-bit security. And, in appendix C2, the signature has four integers, which I (perhaps mistakenly) took as two points.

Comment: One should be able to achieve the same size as with BLS (when instantiating with with the same setting as BLS). Where do you take the numbers for BLS?

Comment: @DrLecter: I have been trusting Thomas Pornin's http://security.stackexchange.com/a/112145 and http://security.stackexchange.com/a/33047 without diving into to math; which will take me a lot of time, since I'm discovering paring-based cryptography on the late, and with the math background of an engineer.

Comment: In appendix C2 the signature is "S = (Sx,Sy)", which is one point.

Comment: Thomas Pornin says "at least". In BLS you are not working in elliptic curves where only the generic attack applies, but rather in pairing groups. So the size of the signature also depends on the embedding degree, which tells you how to choose the base field of the curve such that the discrete log in the target group achieves your desired security level. In the original BLS paper the choice of the curve is so that the signatures are indeed very short. But this does not hold for supersingular curves or BN curves in general as used in your cited drafts.

Comment: Ah, got it for the single point being expressed as 4 integers in [appendix C.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-zss-02#appendix-C.2); we are working on a curve in $\mathbb F_{p^2}$, without point compression. While I mostly understand point compression in normal ECC, I won't venture alone on translating that to PBC.

Comment: @fgrieu If the point is on a specific curve, I don't see how compression wouldn't work.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: for curves of the form $y^2=x^3+a\cdot x+b$, in a base group where computing square roots is easy and there are few of these, agreed. But do groups suitable for pairings universally match this..